# How to redirect powershell.exe OUPUT and ERROR to two separate files?

Tags: powershell

I need to redirect the STDERR and STDOUT to two separate files.

I tried the following:

- This will output error only to an error file:

  ```
  powershell.exe -file c:\test.ps1 2> test.txt
  ```
- This will output all output to a result file:

  ```
  powershell.exe -file c:\test.ps1 2>&1> test.txt
  ```

My question is how can I redirect STDERR and STDOUT to two separate files by running `powershell.exe` just once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify multiple redirections. Ex.

```
powershell.exe -file Sample.ps1 2>errors.txt 1>output.txt
```

Sample.ps1

```
Write-Error "This is a critial error"
Write-Output "This is output"
"This is also output"
```

Errors.txt

```
C:\Users\frode\Desktop\Sample.ps1 : This is a critial error
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Untitled202.ps1
```

Output.txt

```
This is output
This is also output
```

Comment: [Related](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection). [Also related](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Frode and Ansgar